# What does the b'' sentinel mean in Python iter()?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a process that returns a bunch of lines, which I want to iterate through:

```
import subprocess

myCmd = ['foo', '--bar', '--baz']
myProcess = subprocess.Popen(myCmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for myLine in iter(myProcess.stdout.readline, b''):
    print myLine
```

What does the sentinel argument to [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) do in this example, where I pass it the value `b''`? I think I understand `''` by itself — I stop iterating on an empty line — but I don't know what `b''` means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python3 the string is a byteliteral. Ignored in python 2.

Comment: I have been writing Python 2.x scripts, so I wouldn't have caught this detail. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: Usually work with python2 myself aswell. Just stumbled along this when handling strings with char values 0-255 instead of UTF symbols

Comment: I'd like to point out that putting it this way is _not_ correct.

Comment: Please educate us @ClassStacker

Comment: I have provided an alternative answer. I hope @AlexReynolds appreciates it.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try my best to be more precise than what I read so far. (Slightly revised version)

The Python notation `b'string'` denotes a byte string literal in Python versions which supports it. The notation has been introduced with [PEP 358](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/) for Python 2 as a step towards the migration to unicode support. The current [Python syntax for 2.6 does not mention the `b` prefix](http://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) while the [Python syntax for 2.7 does mention the `b` prefix](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). However, PEP 358 was intended for Python 2.6 and all Python 2.6 interpreters which I have seen accept it.

With the migration to Python 3, the *default* for string literals changed from *byte* to *unicode*. However, the [`__future__` module](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/__future__.html) was introduced to ease migration. The following illustrates the effect with respect to string literals.

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'abc'
'abc'
>>> b'abc'
'abc'
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> 'abc'
u'abc'
>>> b'abc'
'abc'
```

I hope I could motivate that the following statements have a limited validity:

- *In Python 3 this denotes a byte literal*: Yes, but also in Python 2 at least since version 2.6.
- *This notation is ignored in Python 2*: It is more that it has no effect *if* you have a Python 2 version which already supports it and *unless* you (or the foreign code you look at) imports `__future__` *and only* if you do not care about compatibility with Python 3 (which *everyone* should consider and which is often aimed at in third party software).

The shortest valid answer to the OP's question, in my view, would be:

*This is a prefix for string literals, enforcing byte representation as opposed to unicode representation, introduced in Python 2.6, not changing the Python default for Python 2* (but deserves attention if `from __future__ import` can be seen).